# Group by combining rows

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table like this

| ID | COUNTRY | AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | USA | 100 |
| 2 | USA | 100 |
| 3 | USA | 100 |
| 4 | FRA | 100 |
| 5 | ITA | 100 |
| 6 | ITA | 100 |
| 7 | FRA | 100 |

It is posible to use group by and combine certain values to get as a result a table like this?

| ID | COUNTRY | AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | USA | 300 |
| 2 | EUR | 400 |

Comment: What have you tried till now?

Comment: To confirm, you want the ID values to change when you use group by?

Comment: It isn't necesary to change the ID. The idea is to combine rows following certain rules

Comment: I think IDs are 1,2,3,4 and corresponding countries are EUR, aren't they?

Comment: @Tom Care to specify what those rules are?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `group by` with *conditional*

```
select (case when country = 'USA' then 'USA' else 'EUR' end) COUNTRY,
        sum(AMOUNT) AMOUNT, MONTH 
from table t
group by (case when country = 'USA' then 'USA' else 'EUR' end), MONTH ;
```

Comment: I try it and works, but I just realize that the query was more complex. I edited the question.

Comment: @Tom . . . Significantly editing a question after it has been answered is rude, because it can invalidate answers, leading to downvotes.  Instead, take it as a learning exercise and ask a new and better question.